PyTorch TensorBoard SummaryWriter giving empty metrics
I've been setting up tensorboard with PyTorch. Originally I was using lightning, and ran into an issue where I would log my hyperparameter, but the metrics in the HPARAMS tab would be empty. So, to pin point the issue I moved over to the simplest possible example and the issue is still happening
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
writer = SummaryWriter(log_dir="tb_logs/test")
writer.add_hparams({"a": 0, "b": 0}, {"hparam/test_accuracy": 0.5})
writer.add_hparams({"a": 0, "b": 1}, {"hparam/test_accuracy": 0.6})
writer.add_hparams({"a": 1, "b": 0}, {"hparam/test_accuracy": 0.61})
writer.add_hparams({"a": 1, "b": 1}, {"hparam/test_accuracy": 0.4})
writer.add_hparams({"a": 2.0, "b": 1.5}, {"hparam/test_accuracy": 0.7})

Per the PyTorch docs I'd expect to this exact table in the HPARAMS tab, but when I go I am met with this instead (https://imgur.com/a/zb1yTPA)
I am using
lightning               2.4.0
torch                   2.4.0
tensorboard             2.17.0


It works fine for me with PyTorch version: 2.3.1+cu121 and TensorBoard version: 2.17.0

What happens when you try to flush or add another empty line at the end ? you can also try to modify the parameter flush_secs(=120 by default) . https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensorboard.html#torch.utils.tensorboard.writer.SummaryWriter

Having the same issue... Did you manage to solve it?

I met the same issue using pytorch=2.4.1 and tensorboard=2.18. But it works well in a conda environment with pytorch=1.12.1 and tensorboard=2.10. Considering comment from Sachin Hosmani that pyTorch=2.3.1 and tensorBoard=2.17.0 work fine, I think there might be some bugs in pytorch 2.4.
The written log files don't have bugs. Just use the an old version environment to start the tensorboard server and the values can be displayed normally.

This is a tensorboard issue with the current version. Downgrade to 2.16.2 fixes the issue.
pip install tensorboard==2.16.2
